# App Engine JDO contains on Set property

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jdo

I have the following class:

```
@PersistenceCapable
public class User implements Serializable {

@PrimaryKey
private long userId;

@Persistent(defaultFetchGroup = "true")
private Set<String> deviceIds;

@Persistent(defaultFetchGroup = "true")
private long schoolClass;

@Persistent(defaultFetchGroup = "true")
private Set<Long> subjects;
}
```

When I'm doing a query with contains I always get an empty list

```
PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
Query q = pm.newQuery(User.class);
q.setFilter("subjects.contains(subject)");
List<User> userList = (List<User>) q.execute(Arrays.asList(new Long(13)));
q.closeAll();
```

What am I doing wrong? There are two two users in the datastore that have the long value 13 in their subject set. So the query should return two results.

When I deug this query then I see that there is an InvocationException when I click on userList right after q.execute().

Comment: are you sure that GAE supports that query in the datastore ? looking at the log (DEBUG level) would reveal many things

Comment: great, there's an "InvocationException", which no doubt has a nested exception and stack trace. So why not provide that information, and the rest of the info from the log about what underlying query is being used.